# DOMDocument::load(): attributes construct error; xslt, select

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to simple walk a path down on a xml-file to a element. But it didnt work.

.xsl

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head><title></title></head>

<body>
<h2>ECU</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>FRAMES</th>
      <th>TIME-PERIOD</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="AUTOSAR/AR-PACKAGES/AR-PACKAGE[SHORT-NAME='GMC']">
<!--    <xsl:for-each select="AUTOSAR/AR-PACKAGES/AR-PACKAGE">-->
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SHORT-NAME" /></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

But when i change the line

```
<xsl:for-each select="AUTOSAR/AR-PACKAGES/AR-PACKAGE">
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each select="AUTOSAR/AR-PACKAGES/AR-PACKAGE[SHORT-NAME='GMC']">
```

the result is getting from this
[all Packages are shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daffu.png)

to a blank page with the error:

```
DOMDocument::load(): attributes construct error
```

The XML ist to large to post it.
**UPDATE #1**:

The .xsl is the hole XSLT file!
The transformation is done under PHP in a spache server (serverside) (see: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_server.asp).

For example the XML snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file was saved with a tool from Vector Informatik GmbH
-->
<AUTOSAR xmlns="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0 AUTOSAR_4-1-1.xsd">
  <ADMIN-DATA/>
  <AR-PACKAGES>
    <AR-PACKAGE UUID="4820f45c-9a5b-49a2-883f-0c7540cf181f">
      <SHORT-NAME>GMC</SHORT-NAME>
            ...
    <AR-PACKAGE UUID="4820f45c-9a5b-49a2-883f-0c7540cf182f">
      <SHORT-NAME>AutosarTEPackage</SHORT-NAME>
            <ROOT-SW-COMPOSITION-PROTOTYPE UUID="9979918152ce3777d6360de31">
              <SHORT-NAME>HighFeatureRootCompositionType</SHORT-NAME>
              <SOFTWARE-COMPOSITION-TREF DEST="COMPOSITION-SW-COMPONENT-TYPE">/AutosarTEPackage/System/HighFeatureRootCompositionType</SOFTWARE-COMPOSITION-TREF>
            </ROOT-SW-COMPOSITION-PROTOTYPE>
    <AR-PACKAGE UUID="4820f45c-9a5b-49a2-883f-0c7540cf183f">
      <SHORT-NAME>Communication</SHORT-NAME>
...
...
    </AR-PACKAGE>
  </AR-PACKAGES>
</AUTOSAR>
```

Comment: You can't a post snippet of XML and what processor are you using causing this error? Finally, please post entire XSLT to see if other templates/namespaces are relevant.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're much more likely to get good responses to questions here if you show what you have tried, in a form that allows others to reproduce the problem (difficult, of course, if you have no idea where to start).  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).